# Using Thunderbird to connect (to Yahoo for example) the connection hangs up and it goes no where

Tags: email, thunderbird

there are a number of messages that appear in the command line window after i push send or get messages.. but I get no connection, nothing is received or sent.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 lts. and this particular system has been connecting to yahoo without a problem until yesterday.
I have reinstalled the thunderbird with no difference in result

how can i track this down?

one person suggested it was due to an extra / in a select command somewhere but I do not know..

Comment: It's interesting that echoing IMAP "0 LOGIN user password" command via openssl to imap.mail.yahoo.com:993 and SMTP "EHLO user/LOGIN/base64 user/base64 password" works, but thunderbird stalls.

Answer (score 2):

Since Verizon purchased Yahoo, and since your ISP is probably AT&T, the Yahoo mail servers have been changed to AT&T servers.

For POP, use...

```
inbound.att.net
995, SSL

outbound.att.net
465, SSL, req auth
```

For IMAP, use...

```
imap.mail.att.net
993, SSL

smtp.mail.att.net
465/587, SSL, req auth
```

Comment: Wow even Yahoo itself did not update these details. To add confusion, openssl connections to Yahoo's original IMAP and SMTP servers work, although the show different responses (e.g. "0 OK AUTHENTICATE completed" with att.net vs "0 OK LOGIN completed" with yahoo.com from time to time). Att's IMAP server also adds "imapgate-VERSION" and more capabilities in its initial OK response.

Comment: Checking with the source code https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mailnews/imap/src/nsImapProtocol.cpp#l5958 shows "0 authenticate plain", e.g., `{ echo -ne "0 authenticate plain\r\n"; sleep 5; echo -ne "REDACTED_BASE64_OF_NUL_USER_NUL_PASSWORD\r\n"; sleep 5; echo -ne "0 status inbox (messages)\r\n0 logout\r\n"; sleep 5; } | openssl s_client -connect imap.mail.yahoo.com:993`.  Both yahoo.com and att.net respond with "+ \r\n0 OK AUTHENTICATE completed\r\n" followed by the inbox status, but sometimes yahoo.com says "+ \r\nDONE\r\n".